# DevTestLabs VirtualNetwork-Subnet: inconsistency between portal and .net sdk

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-virtual-network, azure-devtest-labs

[image]

I'm trying to set `Use in virtual machine creation` and `Allow public IP creation` to `Yes` programmatically. I found the right method, here's my code for that:

```
var fragment = new VirtualNetworkFragment(
    subnetOverrides: virtualNetwork.Subnets.Select(s =>
        new SubnetOverrideFragment(
            labSubnetName: s.Key,
            resourceId: s.Value.Inner.Id,
            useInVmCreationPermission: "Allow",
            usePublicIpAddressPermission: "Allow")).ToList());

var vnet = await BaseClientFactory.CreateDevTestLabClient(azureClient)
    .VirtualNetworks
    .UpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(dbLab.ResourceGroupName, dbLab.LabId.ToString(), virtualNetworkId, fragment);
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work but it doesn't throw any exception, either. When I serialize `fragment` variable to compare it with the request that's sent when doing this manually on Azure, there is a small difference.

Here is how the body looks like in the code when it's serialized using NewtonsoftJson (I took it from the Watch window):
[image]

Here is how the body looks like when sent via Azure:
[image]

The only two changes is that my code generates a request where `allowedSubnets` are `null` and (more importantly, I reckon) the structure differs a little in the way that my code generates `properties.subnetOverrides` instead of a proper json structure. I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, the [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dtl/virtualnetworks/update) action just can be used to modify tags of virtual networks and all other properties will be ignored. If you want to modify the properties of virtual networks, please use [Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dtl/virtualnetworks/createorupdate) action. Regarding how to implement with c# sdk `Microsoft.Azure.Management.DevTestLabs`, please refer to the following steps

1. [Create a service principal and assign role to the sp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-5.3.0)
2. Code

```
            string clientId = " sp appId";
            string clientSecret = "sp password";
            string tenantId = "";
            string subscriptionId = "";
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    tenantId,
                    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

            DevTestLabsClient client = new DevTestLabsClient(credentials);
            client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
            VirtualNetwork vnet = await client.VirtualNetworks.GetAsync("testdevlab", "test", "Dtltest");
             // modify the vent's properties 
             vnet.SubnetOverrides = vnet.SubnetOverrides.Select(s => { s.UseInVmCreationPermission = "Allow"; s.UsePublicIpAddressPermission = "Allow"; return s; }).ToList();
            //update vnet
            var res =await client.VirtualNetworks.CreateOrUpdateAsync("testdevlab", "test", "Dtltest", vnet);
```

Before running code
[image]

After running code
[image]

Comment: I've tried that method, too, but the problem is that `SubnetOverrides` is null after fetching it with DevTestLabsClient. Any idea why? I can see there are subnets on the azure portal. `AllowedSubnets` are empty.

Comment: It's okay, though, I just download the vnet with `IAzure` service and then seed `SubnetOverrides` with `Subnets` coming from `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent.NetworkImpl`. When I save it with the method you suggested, it works. Thanks !